# How Can I Successfully Migrate Skype Data?

Tags: skype

I'm looking to create a new Skype account, but have things pick up right where they left off for my contacts.

I've already transferred the Skype AppData information, but I have a slightly more advanced question.

How can I make it so my contacts have the chat history from my last account?

i.e. I want them to be able to open a conversation with my NEW skype account and see our last words from my OLD skype account. What do they have to do to make this possible?

Comment: Pretty sure that is not possible because chat history is stored locally on each individuals computer.

Answer (score 2):

The Skype message history is stored in only one file: On Windows 7, it's `C:\Users\<yourname>\AppData\Roaming\Skype\<yourskypename>\main.db`. Try to copy this file to the other account (while Skype is not running, obviously). I haven't tried that, but I have successfully restored all my message logs with only this one file from backups.

If you just copied your whole `AppData\Skype\` folder, it doesn't work if you don't change the `<yourskypename>` part according to your other account name. But that should be all there is to do! Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I cut and paste my messenger conversations from Skype into word documents and keep them in my customer files, to have an ongoing record of what we discuss. :)  I realise this is not the same as having the originals, but hope that it is also useful!